# Error al exportar en excell reporte SSRS

Tags: ssrs

[image: Reporte con la columna que provoca el error al exportar en excell]

Buenos dias, estoy realizando un report ssrs, pero al realizar la exportacion en excell, me la realiza incompleta.
[image: tipo exportacion]

La fila que subrayo en la primera imagen es la que me esta causando problemas. esta fila es para realizar la sumatoria de totales de los grupo, para las columnas que ahi se ven en la imagen, esta fila no es parte del grupo
[image: excell con el problema]